# What is the power of the seventh Witch?

Tags: yamada-and-the-7-witches

What exactly is her power?

Why did Miyamura's sister, Yamada, and the president not get affected by her memory erase?

I understand that perhaps she couldn't erase Yamada's memories, but then how did the other evade the memory erase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 7th witches power is the the power to forget everything about the witches.

Miyamura's Sister ran away from her and escaped so was not affected. She's hasn't returned to the school since.

Yamada's power reversed the power and everyone else forgot about him and the witches.

The president was not affected because the student council president is the only student who may be immune to the witches' powers.

There's some fan speculation that the presidents are people who have Yamada's power, or have had.

[image]

Comment: I'll try find the exact scene where it mentions the student council president later, but I'm in work atm ^^

Comment: I guess I should also ask what exactly did the 7th witch do? If she didn't kiss Yamada, how did her powers activate? Also I found the part where the Prez tells Yamada it is just an "iron-clad law" that only the president may know of the 7 witches.

Comment: I'm starting to get more curious about this absolute law where the only person that can know all 7 witches is the president. If both Tamaki and Yamada learned about the 7th witch from Miya's Sister, then how did the witch know that they knew? Even the president doesn't have this knowledge, which is why he asked Yamada.

Comment: oh yeah, I forgot that she didn't actually kiss him. I have a feeling that the plot point might be revealed once Yamada retrieves the second book detailing the witches.



I'd say the 7th witch probably heard all the huckus that Yamada was making around the school, and found out that way. I have no solid evidence for that though

Comment: No Yamazaki ( the four eyes president ) was affected by the seventh witch's power and forgot about leona ( miyamura's sister ) and the witches then the seventh witch (saionji rika ) pushed him to become president

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate. The power of the 7th witch is to make everyone, except for her target, forget everything about the witches.

Comment: @nhahtdh - I haven't been keeping up with the series - feel free to edit your stuff in or put a new updated answer

Answer (score 0):

The 7th witch's power is memory manipulation. She/he also has the power to see the witches out of the students in the school. This power was revealed on the second witch war arc when Yamada became the seventh witch.